# NiFi: Problems with user rights

Tags: apache-nifi

**NiFi 1.10.0 https**

2 Users are configured: **users.xml**

```
<users>
    <user identifier="8c3010a2-93a9-3ca5-ab83-f57379f0dc41" identity="CN=NiFi_frl, OU=WERK2, O=Fischer, L=Stahringen, C=Germany"/>
    <user identifier="8776e4de-0171-1000-f9a4-9cda2036fc56" identity="CN=NiFi_Fischer, OU=WERK2, O=Fischer, L=Stahringen, C=Germany"/>
</users>
```

The certificates are OK, I can login with both certificates.

Both users have a lot of rights, including view and modify the controllers. See:
[Screenshot: user policies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWqqh.jpg)

One user is the "*Initial Admin Identity*". **authorizers.xml**

```
<accessPolicyProvider>
    <identifier>file-access-policy-provider</identifier>
    ...
    <property name="Initial Admin Identity">CN=NiFi_Fischer, OU=WERK2, O=Fischer, L=Stahringen, C=Germany</property>
    ...
</accessPolicyProvider>
```

**Problem**:

If I login to NiFi (https), the user name is shown and I can add users, change policies. But I can't edit the workflows / processors

Example User 'NiFi_frl' with Firefox Browser: 
[Screenshot: User: frl Browser: Firefox: no edit rights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MVMP.jpg)

Example User 'NiFi_Fischer' with Chrome Browser:
[Screenshot: User: Fischer Browser: Chrome: no edit rights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8D2D.jpg)

I've tried to add a new user (incl. certificate), give him all rihts to controller etc.
but after login ist the same: I can see the controllers but can't edit them

Any idea, what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give yourself modify permissions to the root process group. You can do that by clicking the policy icon in the palette on the left hand side (when nothing else is selected on the canvas). Then create new policy for "modify the component" and add your user.